# When trying to restore a database backup from Azure SQL on a local SSMS, it doesn't do it and shows errors

Tags: sql, azure, ssms, backup, restore

When trying to restore a database backup from Azure SQL on a local SSMS (v19.x), it can't proceed and shows errors:

Could not import package.

Warning SQL72012: The object [Identity_2023-02-14_Data] exists in the target, but it will not be dropped even though you selected the 'Generate drop statements for objects that are in the target database but that are not in the source' check box.

Warning SQL72012: The object [Identity_2023-02-14_Log] exists in the target, but it will not be dropped even though you selected the 'Generate drop statements for objects that are in the target database but that are not in the source' check box.

Error SQL72014: Framework Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 35221, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Could not process the operation.

Always On Availability Groups replica manager is disabled on this instance of SQL Server. Enable Always On Availability Groups, by using the SQL Server Configuration Manager. Then, restart the SQL Server service, and retry the currently operation. For information about how to enable and disable Always On Availability Groups, see SQL Server Books Online.

Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:

ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
ADD FILE (NAME = [XTP_704A0C41], FILENAME = N'$(DefaultDataPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_XTP_704A0C41.mdf') TO FILEGROUP [XTP];

Answer (score 0):

**Error SQL72014**

To resolve this error, you need to enable contained database authentication on the SQL Server instance as mentioned by @[ShaktiSingh-MSFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1161037/import-bacpac-to-local-sql-server-failed-with-sql7)

BY following @ [Windhoek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57595926/could-not-import-package-warning-sql72012-the-object-exists-in-the-target) documentation you will find same issue is raised and resolved  .

```
sp_configure 'contained database authentication', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

Here The `sp_configure 'contained database authentication', 1` command is used to enable contained database authentication in SQL Server.

Refer this [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/contained-database-authentication-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver16) for more information
[image]
You can Refer this  [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73913304/error-sql72014-occured-while-importing-database-bacpac-file-in-azure-sql-server) thread also .

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and had a terrible time tracking down the issue. Tried the suggestions above with no luck. Turns out I just didn't have one of the add-on features installed for my sql server(specifically the full text search).

In order to fix this I simply installed the feature to my existing server(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/add-features-to-an-instance-of-sql-server-setup?view=sql-server-ver16) and then the import worked perfectly. Maybe someone else will have a similar issue, hopefully this helps.