# Encountered a SQL72014 error when I tried to restore the database backup

Tags: sql, azure, ssms, backup, restore

Using SSMS, I have created a `.bacpac` file and encountered errors SQL72014 and SQL2045 when trying to restore the database:

> Failed to import package.
>
> Error SQL72014: Framework Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider:
>
> Msg 128, Level 17, State 1, Procedure CopyToTestDB, Line 5
> Incorrect syntax near 'copy'.
>
> Error SQL72045: Script execution error.

I have tried as shown below but couldn't figure out:

```
 sp_configure 'contained database authentication', -1;
 GO
 RECONFIGURE;
 GO
```

Comment: could you share some code with us ? does it work if you restore manually ?

Comment: sp_configure 'contained database authentication', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO

once try this and refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75516392/when-trying-to-restore-a-database-backup-from-azure-sql-on-a-local-ssms-it-does/75518350#75518350

Comment: @Thomas - Thanks for your comment. No it is not working manually. I am encountered with the above error when I have tried to create a copy from Azure SQL. Apologies  that I couldn't share the code at this moment.

Comment: @vijaya - Thanks for your comment. Let me verify the database authentication changing it to 1 as suggested. Will confirm you once verified.

Comment: @vijaya - Thanks for the suggestion - Happy that it is working now. You can mark your comment as a solution - will accept it.